# Android : with command --prod : statement not working

Tags: android, angular, ionic2, ionic3

We are working on an app project with ionic3 for android. in the code we have :

```ts
if(this.nav.getActive().name != "LicenceFiniPage" && this.nav.getActive().name != "DetailsPage" && this.nav.getActive().name != "DetailsAnalysePage" && this.nav.getActive().name != "LoginPage" && this.licence == "OK"){
   this.nav.push(AnalysesPage); 
}
```

When we try to test with the command `ionic cordova run android` it works fine but when we export the apk to the store with the command: `ionic cordova build --release --prod android` the statement `if` above is not working any more

Comment: Do you have a plugin `cordova-plugin-ionic`, accessing Ionic Pro Live Deploy?

Comment: Hello @Mystery how can I verify that please?

Comment: Type `ionic cordova plugin list` in the terminal or you can look at your `package.json` if you installed it. You can look at your `app.module.ts` if you used it.

Comment: Hello @Mystery thank you a lot 
I don't have that plugin installed
SHould I install it ? How to install it? Will it make --prod give same behaviour as ionic cordova run android ?
Thank youfor your help

Comment: No. Im just thinking if you have that one because if you upload your apk to store, the app will always get the live deploy version. So if you didnt update your  live deploy repo, you will be seeing the old app version instead of the new update from the store.